# Specifying ggplot2 aesthetics for factors stored in SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: r, contour, sp, ggplot2, spatialdataframe

I produced a set of 2 contour lines for 6 different individuals. The contours for each individual were originally stored in a single list which contained 6 separate SpatialLinesDataFrames (one per individual).

I used `NewDf <- do.call(rbind, OriginalList)` to combine these into a single SpatialLinesDataFrame so that I can plot them on a single map with geom_path. `NewDf` now returns this structure:

```r
> NewDf

class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 12 
extent      : .....
crs         : ....
variables   : 2
names       : level,   Individual 
min values  :   0.5, 21545 
max values  :  0.95, 32156
```

I can plot all contours using this:

```r
ggplot()+
  geom_path(data = NewDf, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)
```

but I want to color each set by `Individual`. I find that you can access the factor `Individual` using `NewDf@data$Individual`, but I cannot figure out how to refer to this in the `ggplot` call (e.g. `ggplot()+geom_path(data = a, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, col = data$Individual))` does not work)

How do you access factors stored in a SpatialLinesDataFrame for mapping aesthetics in ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot` doesn't know what do with sp-class spatial objects. It passes them into the `fortify` function and then works with the result. That's where the `long`, `lat` and `group` names come from that you used in the `geom_path` call.

The "fortified" spatial lines object drops all its columns, retaining only coordinates and structure of how to construct the features in its `id` and `group` columns. Here's one created from the `Sl` object created in the help page `class?SpatialLines`:

```
> sldf = SpatialLinesDataFrame(Sl,data=data.frame(NAME=c("First","Second")),match.ID=FALSE)
```

The data part of this is:

```
> sldf@data
    NAME
1  First
2 Second
```

but when fortified becomes:

```
> fortify(sldf)
  long  lat order piece id group
1 1.00 3.00     1     1  a   a.1
2 2.00 2.00     2     1  a   a.1
3 3.00 2.00     3     1  a   a.1
4 1.05 3.05     4     2  a   a.2
5 2.05 2.05     5     2  a   a.2
6 3.05 2.05     6     2  a   a.2
7 1.00 1.00     1     1  b   b.1
8 2.00 1.50     2     1  b   b.1
9 3.00 1.00     3     1  b   b.1
```

If you want to add extra columns from your spatial lines to this you need to match them up based on the `id` column, which is also the `row.names` of the spatial lines. Use the match to extract rows from the spatial lines that match the fortified data frame, pull these out and column-bind them onto the fortified data frame to get a wider fortified data frame:

```
> fd = fortify(sldf)
> fd = cbind(fd, data.frame(sldf[match(fd$id, row.names(sldf)),]))
> fd
    long  lat order piece id group   NAME
1   1.00 3.00     1     1  a   a.1  First
1.1 2.00 2.00     2     1  a   a.1  First
1.2 3.00 2.00     3     1  a   a.1  First
1.3 1.05 3.05     4     2  a   a.2  First
1.4 2.05 2.05     5     2  a   a.2  First
1.5 3.05 2.05     6     2  a   a.2  First
2   1.00 1.00     1     1  b   b.1 Second
2.1 2.00 1.50     2     1  b   b.1 Second
2.2 3.00 1.00     3     1  b   b.1 Second
```

Then you can do this:

```
> ggplot() + geom_path(data=fd, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, col=NAME))
>
```

At this point (or actually for me, well before this point) you remember what a pain sp-class objects are to deal with and suggest trying to do everything with the new `sf` class spatial objects and the `geom_sf` function, which understands all the columns of `sf` spatial data frames. Conversion from `sp` to `sf` is simple enough.

Comment: did you save the fortify object as `fd`?

Comment: meaning is this missing: `fd <- fortify(sldf)`

Comment: Yes sorry, exactly that. Will edit.